# Open ball containment with different metrics

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have this question:

Let (M,d) me a metric space. Define $$\lambda(x,y) ≡ {d(x,y)\over 1+d(x,y)}$$
Temporarily define:

$$B_λ(p; r) ≡ \{x ∈ M : λ(p, x) < r\},  B(p;r) ≡ \{x ∈ M : d(p, x) < r\}$$Show that, for all $ϵ > 0$ there is a $δ > 0$ such that, for all $p ∈ M,
B(p; δ) ⊆ B_λ(p; ϵ)$; and that, similarly, for all $ϵ > 0$ there is a $δ > 0$ such that, for all $p ∈ M,
B_λ(p; δ) ⊆ B(p; ϵ)$.

My original approach was to re-write $B_λ(p; ϵ)$ so that it can be seen as a ball with the $d(x,y)$ metric. This looks like $B(p;ϵ(1+d(p,x)))$. Then, I thought that $δ$ must simply be less than $ϵ(1+d(p,x))$.  I thought it seemed a little weird defining $δ$ with $d(p,x)$, so I asked my professor about this and he told me that it wouldn't work.  He told me to instead look at $t < δ$ and ${t\over 1+t} < ϵ$.  This gets me stuck in the same spot over and over again, because I just end up defining $δ$ with $t$. Can anyone give me a hint on this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\frac t{1+t}<\epsilon$ and $\epsilon<1$ then $t<\frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$
$$\frac t{1+t}<\epsilon\\t<\epsilon(1+t)=\epsilon+\epsilon t\\t-t\epsilon<\epsilon\\t(1-\epsilon)<\epsilon\\t<\frac\epsilon{1-\epsilon}$$

Comment: OK, I understand why $\epsilon<1$. I'm having a little trouble seeing why $t<{\epsilon\over 1-\epsilon}$ though.

Comment: Got it, thanks!